# SpringBoot, Hibernate and AWS RDS (Aurora) with new CA rds-ca-ecc384-g1

Tags: java, postgresql, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-rds

I have a SpringBoot application that communicates to PostgreSQL with the following configuration, deployed via AWS BeanStalk:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://{SUBDOMAIN}.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/{DATABASE_NAME}
spring.datasource.username={USER}
spring.datasource.password={PASSWORD}
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=2
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation= true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

Everything was going well until I have updated the AWS Aurora certificate to `rds-ca-ecc384-g1`, and now I seemingly cannot connect to Postgres anymore.

The error I receive is:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: SSL error: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at org.postgresql.ssl.MakeSSL.convert(MakeSSL.java:43) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar!/:42.5.4]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.enableSSL(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:620) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar!/:42.5.4]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:191) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar!/:42.5.4]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:258) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar!/:42.5.4]
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:54) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar!/:42.5.4]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:253) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar!/:42.5.4]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:434) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar!/:42.5.4]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:291) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar!/:42.5.4]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:359) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:470) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:100) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:284) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:177) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:36) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:119) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:255) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:230) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.Database.<init>(Database.java:44) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.getDatabase(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:218) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:191) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1348) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1419) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1817) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1155) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.10.jar!/:3.0.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-3.0.10.jar!/:3.0.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-3.0.10.jar!/:3.0.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.0.10.jar!/:3.0.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.10.jar!/:3.0.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.10.jar!/:3.0.10]
    at com.app.Main.main(Main.java:18) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[main-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:95) ~[main-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[main-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65) ~[main-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:365) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:293) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:204) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1510) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1425) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:455) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:426) ~[na:na]
    at org.postgresql.ssl.MakeSSL.convert(MakeSSL.java:41) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar!/:42.5.4]
    ... 59 common frames omitted
```

When I connect manually via `psql` to the database from the same machine, this happens:

```
$ PGSSLMODE=verify-full psql -h {SUBDOMAIN}.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com -p 5432 -U {USER} -W {DATABASE_NAME}
Password:
psql: error: connection to server at "{SUBDOMAIN}.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com" (10.0.156.184), port 5432 failed: root certificate file "/home/ec2-user/.postgresql/root.crt" does not exist
Either provide the file or change sslmode to disable server certificate verification.
```

Comment: The error with psql is clearly a client configuration problem.  It is hard to see how that could have anything to do with the change on the server.

Comment: What error message is found in the server log file?  That will often be more informative than the one reported by the client.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I tried to connect a java app to my Postgres RDS instance after the point and click AWS CA update. AWS updated the CA to `rds-ca-ecc384-g1`. Changing it to `rds-ca-rsa2048-g1` solved the issue. It expires in year 2061 instead of 2121, so it should give us a little bit of time.

If you're in the AWS console, click on an instance of your database, then click Modify on the top right. Scroll down to "Connectivity" section and change it to `rds-ca-rsa2048-g1`. Click Continue on the bottom. "Apply Immediately", then "Modify DB Instance". Wait for AWS to apply changes. For my case, I didn't need to restart the db, just the application.

It seems some libraries can't negotiate the more complex algorithms. I had a psycopg2 app that had no problems with the `rds-ca-ecc384-g1` CA.

Comment: When we change the CA to rds-ca-rsa4096-g1, don't we need to download the certificate file to connect to the RDS server?
I changed the certificate and still got the SSL connectivity error.

Comment: Sorry. I pasted the wrong CA. I meant `rds-ca-rsa2048-g1`. Let me correct my answer

Answer (score 0):

For running application in local, add **?sslmode=disable** after {DATABASE_NAME} in spring.datasource.url

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround for Postgres DBs I used the **rds-ca-rsa4096-g1** encryption instead of rds-ca-ecc384-g1.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem last week. In my case i changed it to **rds-ca-2019** and it worked again